# Evitar repetición de la misma consulta API Rest en Angular

Tags: angular, component, angular9

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Angular 9 en la cual necesito comunicar 2 componentes no relacionados entre sí, me explico con una imagen:

[image: Anidación de componentes]

El **Componente C** es simplemente un campo select con una lista de valores recibidos mediante una consulta API Rest realizada desde el contenedor padre **Componente B**. El problema es que como existen 12 componentes hijos (B), cada uno de ellos va a realizar la petición al servidor mediante una API Rest para obtener la lista de valores que ha de contener el campo select (C), por tanto se harán 12 peticiones al servidor para obtener la misma información.

Necesito alguna forma válida, que respete las buenas prácticas de desarrollo en Angular, que me permita realizar una sola consulta a la Api Rest para rellenar los campos select.

Había pensado en utilizar un servicio que, inyectado en el **Componente A**, realice la consulta 1 sola vez y la guarde en un atributo del mismo servicio, posteriormente en el **componente B** inyecto el mismo servicio y me sirvo de la propiedad que contiene el resultado de la consulta para pasársela mediante un **Input()** al select.

No sé si es la solución ideal dada mi poca experiencia o existe una mejor o más eficiente.

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Hola. Yo suelo crear un 'pool' de datos en el servicio y lo almaceno en el servicio. Asi, en cada componente 'b' llamo al servicio con los datos ya cargados. Cuando se ejecute el `ngOnInit` de A, hago mi operacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución que propones es la forma en la que normalmente se solucionan este tipo de situaciones.
La diferencia a cómo lo planteas, es que el componente `A` no va a proporcionar directamente los resultados a todos los componentes `B`, sino que `A` hace la llamada y delega el `Observable` a los componentes `B`; estos mismos son los se que suscriben a la respuesta y obtienen los datos.

```
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  obs: Observable<SomeResult>;

  constructor(private service: SomeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Aquí no hacemos el subscribe, porque
    // el componente A no necesita el resultado
    this.obs = this.service.someCall();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Por otro lado, el componente `B` va a recibir el `Observable` y se suscribe. De modo que la respuesta a la llamada HTTP se popula en todos los componentes (pero solo hay una, realmente).

```
export class BComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() observable: Observable<SomeResult>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.observable.subscribe(result => {
      // En este punto obtendremos el resultado
      // Una vez se complete la llamada.
      // Todas las instancias de componente B van
      // a recibir estos datos de un solo observable.
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

Deberías renderizar los componentes `B` una vez `obs` ya existe (no significa que la llamada se haya completado, solo que se tiene el `Observable`), para evitar que las instancias de componentes `B` se suscriban a un objeto `undefined`.
Si te surge alguna duda con esto último puedo ampliar la respuesta.

Espero que sirva.